# Chrome Content Script: get in front of jQuery delegated event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have developed a Chrome extension that needs to intercept all form submissions in certain circumstances.

The extension is using **raw JavaScript, no jQuery,** and I'd really like to avoid bloating it up by including jQuery as it's mostly implemented already and, as it's a Chrome extension, cross-browser support isn't necessary :)

This works on most of the sites I've tested the extension on, except for one in particular that uses jQuery's `delegate` function to bind a submission event, and then uses jQuery's `.trigger` method to actually trigger form submission when the submit button is clicked.

I have put together a JSBin that replicates the issue: http://jsbin.com/cuxowo/edit?html,js,output

- jQuery bindings are set up with `.delegate`
- jQuery delegates the `click` event handler for the "submit form" button to a method that calls `.trigger("submit"` on the parent form
- a method similar to the one that initializes my extension is bound to the `click` handler of the "Activate Extension" button

**Steps to Replicate**:

- load the JSBin
- click the "submit form" button
- see that only the handler set up by jQuery is triggered
- click "Activate Extension" to set up the addEventListener handlers
- click the "submit form" button again
- see that, again, only handler set up by jQuery is triggered (**NOTE**: this is where I'd like my `addEventListener` handler to be triggered)
- remove the jQuery delegate to the `click` event on the "submit form" button (deleting the snippet of code and reloading the JSBin works fine)
- activate extension and click "submit form" again
- note that when the jQuery delegated `click` event is not in place, the `addEventListener` handler works!

It seems like the jQuery delegated `click` handler that uses `.trigger("submit"` doesn't actually trigger the `submit` handler set up by `addEventListener` -- it would seem like jQuery only triggers event handlers it set up itself.

How can I ensure my extension's form submission event handlers are triggered even on pages like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to monkeypatch the jQuery `$.event.trigger` method in my extension's content script initialization to accomplish what I needed in this case:

```
// hijack jQuery event handlers if present
if ($ !== undefined && $.event !== undefined && $.event.trigger !== undefined) {
  var orig_handler = $.event.trigger;
  var new_handler = function(event, data, elem) {
    var type = event.type || event;
    var eventObj = new Event(type);

    elem.dispatchEvent(eventObj);

    return orig_handler.apply(event, arguments);
  };

  $.event.trigger = new_handler;
}
```